# Possibility of creating a symfony Favorite service for being injected to manager service

Tags: symfony

I have many Ads entities for which I am developing manager services. These entities are (let's say): **MotorAds**, **RealestateAds**, **ElectronicsAds**,...

To do that, I did the following:

- I created an AbstractManager in which I defined all the common methods (such as *find()*, *findAll()*, ...)
- I extended **AbstractManager** to define **MotorManager**, **RealestateManager**, **ElectronicsManager**
- I created services for all these manager as it is shown in this link [Managing Common Dependencies with Parent Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html)

Since all my Ads entities implements a **FavoriteAwareInterface** which is defined as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Minn\AdsBundle\Manager\Doctrine;

interface FavoriteAwareInterface {

    function addFavorite($favorite);

    function removeFavorite($favorite);

    function getFavorites();
}
```

So, here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to create a service named favorite to be injected to the managers **MotorManager**, **RealestateManager**, **ElectronicsManager**?
2. If you have a good article to read regarding that, I will be happy!

Thanks,